# Localization on data annotation and error validation messages in ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, localization, resources, globalization

How to localize data annotation and validation error messages in ASP.NET CORE 3.1

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "something")]
                [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
                [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                [Display(Name = "Password")]
                public string Password { get; set; }
```

I use the standard implementation of resource files from the Microsoft documentation

```
services.AddLocalization(option => option.ResourcesPath = ProjectConstants.LanguageResourcesPath);

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddViewLocalization(
                    LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                      option => option.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

My Resource Files structure

|-Resoures
|---Controllers
|---Views
|---Models

I am refactoring Identity Pages and can not showing standard error messages in two languages. This example in Microsoft docs does not work for me.. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#dataannotations-localization]
Please someone help me

Comment: Where is your model?Make sure the naming of resource file is correct.You could set LogLevel to `Debug` in `appsettings.Development.json` and check the log when you submit the form.

Comment: In addition to @XingZou answer, [This tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5061604/Developing-Multicultural-ASP-NET-Core-3-2-1-Projec) and [repository](https://github.com/LazZiya/ExpressLocalizationSampleCore3) can help do localization faster.

Comment: Hi, there was a problem naming the resource and I found it, but it came up big. I get an error when I try to make the resource public "InvalidOperationException: Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed."  And also I get an error in Visual Studio for resxcodegenerator "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator failed to produce an output for input file 'Resource.en-US.resx' but did not log a specific error."  I tried my best and I can't fix it, has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For adding DataAnnotations localization on
`InputModel` in default Identity `Register` Pages(located in `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml.cs`),you need to name your resource file like

```
Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel+InputModel.en-US.resx
```

For any nested model in `PageModel`, you need to use `+` instead of `.`

Comment: I never would have figured this out! Where is this documented (if anywhere)?