# Localizing DataAnnotations of scaffolded Identity models

Tags: asp.net-identity, data-annotations, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-core-localization

ASP.NET core 5.0 mvc project, I want to localize **scaffolded Identity** pages.

The view localization works (using `IViewLocalizer` in the scaffolded razor files) but the dataAnnotations localization fails using a shared resource file.

Following the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#dataannotations-localization-2) I have :

**A `DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider` set in `Startup.cs`**

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
            factory.Create(typeof(MyApp.SharedResources));
});
```

**My cultures configured and set in `Startup.cs`**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    ...
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("fr")
        };

        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
    ...
}
```

**A `Resources` folder with**

- An empty class `SharedResources.cs` in the namespace of my app
- The associated resource file `SharedResources.fr.resx`

**My scaffolded Identity pages, i.e `Login.cshtml.cs`, with dataAnnotations:**

```cs
    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is required.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is not a valid email address.")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Password field is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

Despite this my labels and errors messages remain untranslated.

What do I miss? Is there any limitation on scaffolded files?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to [Ryan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539497/8253820), I can get it to works with a dedicated `resx` file named with a `+` because Identity models have nested class.

For the record here is the filename for a scaffolded mvc *Login* model:

```
Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel+InputModel.fr.resx
```